# Exclude specific user_id from args in get_comments

Tags: user-meta, array, author-template, comments

I'm basically using a 'latest comments' system on multiple pages where one specific user is listed as the first reply for a comment - highlighted with special CSS - and then 2-3 normal users below this 'special comment'.

I would like the specific user to be excluded from the list of normal users but I can't figure it out. Sorry if the HTML is a bit of a mess but really it's the second $args array that matters.

```
<?php $args = array(
                'user_id' => $curauth->ID,
                'number' => 5,
                'status' => 'approve',
                'parent' => 0
                );
  $comments = get_comments($args);
  if ( $comments )
   {
 foreach($comments as $c){

echo '<div id="authorcommentsmain">';
echo '<ul id="authorcomments">';
echo '<li>';
echo '<a id="authorcommentlink" href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'"> ';
echo get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
echo '</a>';
echo "</br>";
echo "<div id='authorcommentslatest'><div id='authorcommentsuserphoto'>";
echo userphoto($c->user_id, '', '', array(id => 'latestcommentsprofile'));
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='authorcommentexcerpt'> <p>";
echo my_get_comment_excerpt( $c->comment_ID, 80 );
echo "</p></div></div></li>\n";
echo '</ul></div>';



$comment_meta_args2 = array(
                           'status' => 'approve',
                           'parent' => intval($parent_comment_id),
                           'number' => 1,
                           'user_id' => 1,
                           'order' => ASC
                           );
$replies2 = get_comments($comment_meta_args2);

$parent_comment_id = $c->comment_ID;
$comment_meta_args = array(
                           'status' => 'approve',
                           'parent' => intval($parent_comment_id),
                           'number' => 2,

                           'order' => ASC
                           );
$replies = get_comments($comment_meta_args);


if ( $replies2)
{

foreach($replies2 as $r2) {

    echo '<div id="authorcommentsmainSPECIAL">';
echo '<ul id="authorcommentsSPECIAL">';
echo '<li>';
echo "<div id='authorcommentexcerptSPECIAL'>";
echo "<div id='authorcommentsuserphotoSPECIAL'>";
echo userphoto_thumbnail($r2->user_id, '', '', array(id => 'latestcommentsprofileSPECIAL'));
echo "</div>";
echo    "<div id='authorcommentexcerptSPECIALa'>" .  get_comment_author ($r2->comment_ID) . " says... </div> <div id='authorcommentexcerptSPECIALb'>" . get_comment_excerpt( $r2->comment_ID );
echo "</div></div></li>\n";
echo '</ul></div>';

  }
if ( $replies )
{

foreach($replies as $r) {



echo '<div id="authorcommentsmain2">';
echo '<ul id="authorcomments2">';
echo '<li>';
echo "<div id='authorcommentexcerpt2'>";
echo "<div id='authorcommentsuserphoto2'>";
echo userphoto_thumbnail($r->user_id, '', '', array(id => 'latestcommentsprofile2'));
echo "</div>";
echo    "<div id='authorcommentexcerpt2a'>" .  get_comment_author ($r->comment_ID) . " says: </div> <div id='authorcommentexcerpt2b'>" . get_comment_excerpt( $r->comment_ID );
echo "</div></div></li>\n";
echo '</ul></div>';
}   
    }
}
    }




  } else { echo "<p style='text-align: center'> Nothing! </p>\n";} ?>
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question. Do you want to get a list of comments excluding comments that have been made by a specific user? If so, which user? The one you are referring as `$curauth->ID`?

Comment: No, I'd like to exclude user_id->1 in $comment_meta_args

Comment: I don't understand. If you use `get_comments()` function you get a list of comments. So, you can include/exclude comments accroding with some criteria, for example you can exclude comments made by user with ID = 1. But you say that you don't want to exlucde comments made by user with ID = 1, you want to exlude user with ID = 1. I'm sorry but I can not imagine how to do that. Can you think again about what you are trying to do and explain it again?

Comment: Yes, I mean I'd like to exclude comments made by user with ID = 1, as you said. So it grabs comments by ALL users and excludes comments made by userid =1

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to do a global $wpdb SQL query but how would I incorporate intval($parent_comment_id), is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had to figure this one out myself.

replace $comment_meta_args and $replies with

```
global $wpdb;
 $comment_meta_args="SELECT * FROM `$wpdb->comments`
 WHERE `comment_approved` = 1
 AND    `comment_parent` = (". intval($parent_comment_id) .")
 AND `user_id` != 1 ORDER BY  comment_date ASC LIMIT 3";

$replies=$wpdb->get_results($comment_meta_args);
```